# How do I delete specific attributes in LDAP using ldap-utils command-line?

Tags: command-line, ldap

I'm trying to remove two attributes from LDAP user.

Pseudo command:

```
ldapdelete -D "uid=username,attribute1,attribute2" -w my_pass -h localhost
```

How do I do that?

---

Note: When searching I'm using the following working command:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=my-test,ou=Services,dc=foo,dc=com" -w my_pass -h localhost -b "ou=Non-Enterprise,ou=People,dc=foo,dc=com" -s sub -x -ZZ "(uid=username)"
```

Related:

[How do I delete one attribute in LDAP with LDIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693752/how-do-i-delete-one-attribute-in-ldap-with-ldif)

[Sun Java System Directory Server Enterprise Edition 6.0 Administration Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-0995/bcacx/index.html)

[Examples on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=bash&p=2&q=ldapmodify&ref=simplesearch&type=Code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ldapdelete` is to remove entries, you need to use `ldapmodify` to delete attributes.

This command should remove `attribute1` and `attribute2` from the `username` entry:

```
$ ldapmodify -D "uid=..." -w ... -h ... <<%EOF%
dn: uid=username,ou=Non-Enterprise,ou=People,dc=foo,dc=com
changetype: modify
delete: attribute1
-
delete: attribute2
%EOF%
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to add also ```-x -Z``` to use simple auth and to use StartTLS.